# How can I make this block move up repeatedly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I downloaded a map with the replica of the Empire State Building and the elevator was just for decoration. I wanted it to move and I didn't have the time to make all of those commands. How can I make the elevator move up with only a few command blocks?

Comment: From what I can see there is no easy way to do this, if you want an in detail method then it's possible to do but it will take a lot of command blocks to move the player smoothly between levels. I would also recommend the modded option or the teleportation option. Message me if you really want to do this with command blocks and I'll help design a system.

Comment: Would a method involving redstone and pistons be ok?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the player to move with the elevator that's a whole other can of worms that's nearly impossible without mods. My best bet for the concept you're going for (without moving the player with it) would be to set up a command block for creating a block above where it was before, and another for destroying the block under it, for every level you want to move it up. It's time-consuming and takes a lot of command blocks, though.

Honestly, I would just have a few buttons in the elevator teleporting the player to that specific level. It doesn't break from the immersion or anything, and it's a heck of a lot easier to rig up.

If you're set on a moving elevator, I would look for a mod.